# query geospatial with azure function

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I could not find any document on how to use docuementdb geospatial query using azure function using nodejs:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Areas a 
WHERE ST_WITHIN({'type': 'Point', 'coordinates':[31.9, -4.8]}, a.location)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocumentDB provides support for geospatial queries. You can find the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-geospatial). You can use the `queryDocuments()` function in the node.js SDK found [here](http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-node/DocumentClient.html#queryDocuments).

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Built in binding support for DocumentDB queries is coming soon, but is not yet released. We just wrapped the work up (see issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/289) in our repo for details). Once this is released, there will be a new `sqlQuery` binding property that you can set, with full query parameter support, etc.

Comment: Even without an sqlQuery binding, you can load the node.js SDK in an Azure Function and run that query, no?

Comment: @LarryMaccherone yes, I am planning to do so using node sdk, but do node sdk support geospatial searching?

Comment: Yes, it does. That's what I thought you were asking but Mathew gave the answer to a different question... although I'm very grateful for the useful bit of information. I've added an answer linking to the docs on geospatial queries in DocumentDB below. Please accept my answer if that's what you were asking.

Comment: @LarryMaccherone Matthew is giving me a correct answer about using Azure Function DocumentDB binding. I can also use nodejs module on Azure Function, hope it works.